# Angular 2 Secondary outlet with guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a page with a main router outlet and a secondary outlet.  My goal is for all users to be routed to a content component while only authenticated users will also be routed to a menu component in the secondary outlet.

given the following route, if the guard returns true both outlets are routed properly however if the guard returns falls neither route is completed.

```
{ path: 'content', children:[
    { path: '', component: ContentComponent},
    { path: '', component: UserMenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],outlet: 'menu'}
]},
```

is it possible to set this up in a way where the guard will only cancel the route for the secondary outlet but allow the main outlet to route properly?

Comment: yes it is possible, `canActivate` can be applied to the named router outlet separately and it will not affect the primary route navigation.